# Missing required parameters for [Route: claim_card] [URI: admin/claim_card/{giftcard_id}/{layout_id}/{user_id}/{color_id}]. - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am new to laravel and when created a route, this error is displayed. I am passing complete parameters and can't locate the error.

Here's the route:

```
Route::get('/admin/claim_card/{giftcard_id}/{layout_id}/{user_id}/{color_id}' , 'UserController@claim_card')->name('claim_card');
```

Here's the function:

```
public function claim_card($giftcard_id , $layout_id , $user_id , $color_id)
{
    $card = giftcard_codes::where([['is_active', '=' , 1], ['giftcard_id', '=' ,$giftcard_id], ['layout_id', '=' ,$layout_id]])->first();
    if ($card) {
        $user = User::where('id', $user_id)->first();
        $lay = point_prizes::where('id', $layout_id)->first();
        if ($user->points >= $lay->points) {
            $us['points'] = $user->points - $lay->points;
            $c['is_active'] = 0;
            $co['color_id'] = $color_id;
            $co['is_pending'] = 2;

            cliaim_prizes_transactions::where([['user_id' , $user_id] , ['giftcard_id' , $giftcard_id] , ['layout_id' , $layout_id]])->first()->update($co);

                    $al = new user_alerts();
                    $al->user_id = $user_id;
                    $al->alert = 'Successfully Claimed Giftcard';
                    $al->alert_main = $card->code;
                    $al->save();

                    redeem__requests::where([['giftcard_id' , $giftcard_id] , ['layout' , $layout_id] , ['user_id' , $user_id] , ['is_active' , 1]])->first()->update($c);
                    giftcard_codes::where([['is_active', 1], ['giftcard_id', $giftcard_id], ['layout_id', $layout_id]])->orderby('id', 'DESC')->first()->update($c);
                    return view('admin.redeem_requests' , ['data' => redeem__requests::where('is_active' , 1)->get() , 'alert' => 'Giftcard Given Successfully']);
        }
    }
    else {
        return view('admin.redeem_requests' , ['data' => redeem__requests::where('is_active' , 1)->get() , 'alert' => 'No Code Exists']);
    }
}
```

Here's the view(where I am passing these):

```
<a href="{{action('UserController@claim_card' , [$gift , $lay , $user , $c->id])}}">
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined a route name `claim_card`, so you can call it by **[named route](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/urls#urls-for-named-routes)** with parameter  as like :

```
<a href="{{ route('claim_card' , ['giftcard_id' => $gift , 'layout_id' => $lay , 'user_id' => $user , 'color_id' => $c->id]) }}">
```

Answer (score 3):

You are not passing the correct parameters in the route. You can use Named Routes with the correct parameters. Something like:

```
<a href="{{ route('claim_card', //definition of parameters here// ) }}"
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take look at the other answer given, which is quite equal to yours. In order to keep the site clean and easy to overlook, we try to avoid double answers.